# ControllerAs Syntax when using $scope methods

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to implement `controllerAs` syntax in AngularJS 1.3

I'm starting my function declarations like so:

```
function() {
    var myCtrl = this;
    myCtrl.foo = foo; // works fine
    myCtrl.$on("foo", bar); // fails, says myCtrl.$on is not a function
}
```

Comment: Please add some of your code

Comment: It's not necessary, and would complicate my question. Basically, how do you implement controllerAs syntax when using $scope methods

Comment: `it blows up` is not a very descriptive problem statement ... please show full controller set up and usage of `$scope.$on` within controller context. Did you forget to inject `$scope`? Also if something blows up in javascript it throws errors and none are mentioned

Comment: so there is no way to explicitly state the $scope as I did with `myCtrl.foo = foo;`

Comment: In the future would save you and us time by posting proper code instead of out of context snippets

Answer (score 1):

The controllerAs syntax uses `this` inside controllers which gets bound to `$scope`. But `$scope` is a special object which contain `$watch`, `$on` and other special properties attached to it.

So when you awnt to watch for some variables or listen to events still you must use `$scope` only.

Answer (score 1):

`$scope` and `myCtrl` identifier aren't interchangeable. 'Controller as' is a syntactic sugar that was introduced in 1.2 and tried to fix the experience from `$scope` (at least the part of it that suffered from undesirable effects of scope prototypal inheritance).

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl as myCtrl">
...
app.controller('MyCtrl', function () {
  ...
});
```

is identical to

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
...
app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.myCtrl = this;
  ...
});
```

It doesn't eliminate the need for scope but introduces useful pattern into the controller (note that you don't need to inject `$scope` in the former example, unless you need `$scope.$on`, etc. there).

You can easily see it by yourself by logging both `$scope` and `myCtrl`.