# angular controller as syntax, still need $scope for special occasion?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am using angular's 'controller as somename' syntax.

let's say the below function is my controller

```
function myCOntroller($scope)
{
  $scope.$emit('event');
}
```

the above function is working. I tried like below

```
function myController()
{
  var reference = this;
  reference.$emit('event');
}
```

this is not working. when I can use reference for data bindings. why I can't use it for this kind of things. I thought reference now have all the functions that $scope had. doesn't it makes sense if $emit works this way?

> NOTE: Sorry about the code samples. I just asked this question as a
>   proof of concept, so don't have any real code.

Comment: `$scope` is not the controller itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545060/controlleras-syntax-when-using-scope-methods/29545260#29545260),

'Controller as' is a syntactic sugar that was introduced in 1.2 and tried to fix the experience from $scope (at least the part of it that suffered from undesirable effects of scope prototypal inheritance).

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl as myCtrl">
...
app.controller('MyCtrl', function () {
  ...
});
```

is identical to

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
...
app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.myCtrl = this;
  ...
});
```

It doesn't eliminate the need for scope but introduces useful pattern into the controller (note that you don't need to inject $scope in the former example, unless you need $scope.$on, etc. there).

So use `this` instead of `$scope` when you want it to act as a model.

Answer (score 1):

"controllerAs" doesn't make `this == $scope`.

Using best-practice *before* `controllerAs`, a controller should have been used *with* a scope.

```
angular.module("myApp")
.controller("myController", ["$scope", function MyController ( $scope ) {
    var myControl = { data: 123 };
    $scope.myControl = myControl;
}]);
```

The HTML would then look like

```
<div ng-controller="myController">{{ myControl.data }}</div>
```

With `controllerAs`, `this` is the controller (NOT the `$scope`), which means that you don't have to put anything on the `$scope` and you can just ignore it, most of the time, unless you have a specific need (events, directives with attributes, etc).

`this.$scope == $scope`

```
angular.module("myApp")
.controller("myController", [function MyController ( ) {
    var myController = angular.extend(this, { data: 123 });
    myController.$scope.$emit( /* ... */ );
}]);
```

Which lets you write

```
<div ng-controller="myController as myControl">
    {{ myControl.data }} <!-- === $scope.myControl.data -->
   <!-- "as" sets the name of the controller, on the scope -->
   <!-- $scope.myControl.$scope === $scope -->
</div>
```

Comment: `this.$scope` is undefined, so `myController.$scope.$emit (/*..*/)` will throw an error. [Fiddle without $scope injection](https://jsfiddle.net/n7p4609r/1/). [Working fiddle with $scope injected](https://jsfiddle.net/srgw8u8h/1/)